# 404 error handling

Tags: web-applications, coldfusion, application.cfc

I am trying to configure the application.cfc to include error handling.
I have this:

```
/**
 * @hint ColdFusion received a request for a non-existent page.
 */
public boolean function onMissingTemplate(String targetPage) {
    return true;
}
```

This does not work, I tried to use

```
include 404.cfm;
```

but no such luck.
Can somebody help out with error handling with the new script style Application.cfc
thanks!
Johnny

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an "answer" per se...

What do you mean by "does not work"? What were you expecting it to do?  And what did it do instead?  Never ever ask a question about something explain why you're asking by saying something "didn't work". That tells us nothing.  We don't even know if your expectations are correct, let alone whether the thing is working properly or not, or in what way it's "not working".

You have a syntax error in your code:

```
include 404.cfm;
```

should be:

```
include "404.cfm";
```

Have you read the docs and tried the example therein: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d2a.html?

> Can somebody help out with error handling with the new script style
>   Application.cfc

Sure. What about it are you having problems with? If you fine-tune your question to explain what you're struggling with in particular, we can help.

I'm gonna vote down your question for being vague, but will keep an eye on it in case you revise it so it explains your situation properly and in such a way you can expect people to be able to help you.  But read the docs, too.